# Write styled Text in a RichTextBox from CaretPosition

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, inline, flowdocument

I have a WPF `RichTextBox` with some standard buttons for text styling. As they should all work the same way, I am going to use the example of making text bold from now on.
So, my goal is, that the user may click the bold-button and then, the text he writes will be bold from wherever the caret was at this point.
The styling has to be set in the inlines of the flow document (because I have to transfer the whole text, including the styling, to another object as xaml string).
At this point, I'm going to post my code. Please note, that this is a simple test project I created to test ways to solve this specific problem.

First the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="rtbTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:rtbTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DockPanel
            Grid.Row="0"
            LastChildFill="False">
            <StackPanel
            DockPanel.Dock="Left"    
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            Background="Gray">
                <TextBlock
                Foreground="#000000"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="Font" 
             />
                <ComboBox 
                x:Name="fonts" 
                Margin="10,2,20,2"
                >
                </ComboBox>
                <TextBlock
                Foreground="#000000"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="Size" 
             />
                <ComboBox 
                x:Name="fontsize" 
                Margin="10,2,20,2"
                >
                </ComboBox>
                <ToggleButton
                x:Name="bold"
                Content="B"
                Margin="0,2,5,2"
                Width="30">
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton
                x:Name="italic"
                Content="I"
                Margin="0,2,5,2"
                Width="30">
                </ToggleButton>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>

        <RichTextBox
            Name="textbox"
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        </RichTextBox>

        <ScrollViewer
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Margin="0,10,0,0"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel
                    Name="entrys"
                    Background="Black"
                    >
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And then the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using function = System.String;
namespace rtbTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.InitializeTextStyling();
        }

        private void InitializeTextStyling()
        {
            this.AddFonts();
            this.fonts.SelectedIndex = 1;
            this.textbox.IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled = true;

            this.fonts.SelectionChanged += (s, a) =>
            {
                if (this.fonts.SelectedIndex != 0)
                {
                    if (this.textbox.Selection.IsEmpty)
                    {
                        this.textbox.Document.FontFamily = ((ComboBoxItem)this.fonts.SelectedItem).Content as FontFamily;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.textbox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty, ((ComboBoxItem)this.fonts.SelectedItem).Content as FontFamily);
                    }
                }
            };


            for (double i = 10; i < 80; i = i + 1)
            {
                this.fontsize.Items.Add(i);
            }
            this.fontsize.SelectionChanged += (s, a) =>
            {
                if (this.textbox.Selection.IsEmpty)
                {
                    this.textbox.Document.FontSize = double.Parse(this.fontsize.SelectedItem.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    this.textbox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, double.Parse(this.fontsize.SelectedItem.ToString()));
                }
            };
            this.fontsize.SelectedItem = 40.0;

            this.italic.Checked += (s, a) =>
            {
                if (this.textbox.Selection.IsEmpty)
                {
                    this.textbox.Document.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.textbox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextBlock.FontStyleProperty, FontStyles.Italic);
                }
            };

            this.italic.Unchecked += (s, a) =>
            {
                if (this.textbox.Selection.IsEmpty)
                {
                    this.textbox.Document.FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.textbox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextBlock.FontStyleProperty, FontStyles.Normal);
                }
            };

            this.bold.Checked += (s, a) =>
            {
                this.textbox.Focus();
                if (this.textbox.Selection.IsEmpty)
                {
                    TextPointer tp = this.textbox.CaretPosition;
                    Run r = new Run("test", tp);
                    r.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                    this.textbox.CaretPosition = r.ElementStart;
                    r.Text = "";
                    string fds = XamlWriter.Save(this.textbox.Document);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.textbox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Heavy);
                }
            };

            this.bold.Unchecked += (s, a) =>
            {
                if (this.textbox.Selection.IsEmpty)
                {
                    this.textbox.Document.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.textbox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal);
                }
            };

            FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
            fd.FontSize = double.Parse(this.fontsize.SelectedItem.ToString());
            fd.FontFamily = ((ComboBoxItem)this.fonts.SelectedItem).Content as FontFamily;
            fd.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
            this.textbox.Document = fd;

        }

        private function GetStringFromStream(Stream stream)
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return r.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }


        private void AddFonts()
        {
            //foreach (System.Drawing.FontFamily f in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families)
            //{
            //    ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
            //    item.Content = new FontFamily(f.GetName(0));
            //    item.FontFamily = (FontFamily)item.Content;
            //    this.fonts.Items.Add(item);
            //}

            ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
            item.Content = new FontFamily("Arial");
            item.FontFamily = (FontFamily)item.Content;
            this.fonts.Items.Add(item);

            item = new ComboBoxItem();
            item.Content = new FontFamily("Corbel");
            item.FontFamily = (FontFamily)item.Content;
            this.fonts.Items.Add(item);

            item = new ComboBoxItem();
            item.Content = new FontFamily("Gabriola");
            item.FontFamily = (FontFamily)item.Content;
            this.fonts.Items.Add(item);

            item = new ComboBoxItem();
            item.Content = new FontFamily("MingLiU - ExtB");
            item.FontFamily = (FontFamily)item.Content;
            this.fonts.Items.Add(item);

            item = new ComboBoxItem();
            item.Content = new FontFamily("MV Boli");
            item.FontFamily = (FontFamily)item.Content;
            this.fonts.Items.Add(item);

            item = new ComboBoxItem();
            item.Content = new FontFamily("Noto Naskh Arabic UI");
            item.FontFamily = (FontFamily)item.Content;
            this.fonts.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This code should be enough to test straight away.

Now, my problem is in this part:

```
this.bold.Checked += (s, a) =>
{
    this.textbox.Focus();
    if (this.textbox.Selection.IsEmpty)
    {
        TextPointer tp = this.textbox.CaretPosition;
        Run r = new Run("test", tp);
        r.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        this.textbox.CaretPosition = r.ElementStart;
        r.Text = "";
        string fds = XamlWriter.Save(this.textbox.Document);
    }
    else
    {
        this.textbox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Heavy);
    }
};
```

What i actually need to do, is insert a `Run` with no text. But if i do this, a Run is inserted in this manner `<Run FontWeight="bold" />` instead of `<Run FontWeight="bold"></Run>.`
I can get the second one (the one I need) when I use the constructor with an initial text like "test" and then I also can set the caret position to the newly created Run. But then i have the text in my RTB, which I don't want. I thought of setting the text in the constructor and later set the text to empty, but if I do so the inserted `Run` reverts again to the first version and I can't set the caret position inside the `Run`.
Is there a way to achieve this: insert a new empty `run` at caret position with the text styled **bold** and the caret position set inside this new run?

Note that the `fds` string was set only so I can see the flow document as XAML string while debugging.

Comment: It's still unclear what and why you are trying to achieve, could you please elaborate more, so people can help :)

Comment: I want to implement a standart text styling like in Microsoft Word for example.
When the user presses the bold button, the text he types should now be bold.
That's why I want to insert a new Run at the caret position with FontWeight bold.